# is it possible to infer the deployment address from the access URL of a report?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I can access a report (named form by the creator) on a SSRS report server, via the following link: http://10.50.79.111/ReportServer_MyOrg/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fMyApp+Reports%2fPayment+Form1&rs:Command=Render&ConID=R2&PayNo=3

If I want to deploy an updated report project to the server, is it possible to infer the deployment address (with the following components) from the URL to access a report?

- TargetServerURL
- TargetReportFolder

?

Is TargetServerURL the part of the form URL before "?" i.e. "http://10.50.79.111/ReportServer_MyOrg/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx"?

Is TargetReportFolder the part of the form URL after "?" and before the first "&"? i.e.
"%2fMyApp+Reports%2fPayment+Form1", i.e. "/MyApp+Reports/Payment+Form1"?
But that is a pathname specific to the form/report, correct? There are more than one forms/reports in the report project, so where can I deploy the report project?

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy a report (from Visual Studio for example) there are two properties that are used.

1. The TargetServerURL = "Http://10.50.79.111/reportserver"
2. Target Report Folder = "MyApp Reports"

Comment: Thanks. Why is the deployment URL so different from the report access URL? What information in the latter can help inferring the deployment URL, and what not?

Comment: If accessed via the standard web portal the default location is http://myservername/reports followed by the folder and report name. The reportserver access is different as you can pass commands via that method and is accessed by default at http://myservername/reportserver . If you navigate the that locations, you'll see all the folders/reports listed.